# Hibernate @OrderBy("firstName ASC") case insensitive?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

we use hibernate and have a team object which contains a list of members:

```
@OrderBy("firstName ASC")
private List<User> members = new ArrayList<User>();
```

But we'd like to have it case insensitive and not sensitive, this way for example a lower letter a will be beneath every other capital letter.
In the [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/) in chapter 2.2.5.3.4. I found how to order using the @OrderBy annotation but there is no hint on how to do this case insensitive.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify case insensitive ordering by annotating ordering column with `LOWER` or `UPPER`

```
@OrderBy("UPPER(firstName) ASC")
private List<User> members = new ArrayList<User>();
```

Below SQL generated by hibernate

```
SELECT user0_.id AS id1_0_0_,
       user0_.firstname AS firstname2_0_1_,
       user0_.lastname AS lastname3_0_1_
FROM user user0_
WHERE user0_.user_id=?
ORDER BY upper(user0_.firstname)
```

Comment: I tried this but I get a persistenceException:   

Exception Description: The order by value [UPPER(firstName)], specified on the element [members] from entity [class [...]Team], is invalid. No property or field with that name exists on the target entity [class [...]User].       Seems like it searches for the attribute UPPER(firstName). Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I did import `OrderBy` from `javax.persistence`, I tried with `JPA` and hibernate `Criteria` it worked

Comment: Could you post your code, are you using JPA Entity manager or Hibernate Session Factory?

Answer (score 0):

To order by something other than a normal field, you have to put it also in the select clause, so

```
SELECT e, UPPER(e.firstName) AS firstNameUpper FROM MyEntity e WHERE ... ORDER BY firstNameUpper ASC
```

Clearly you then have to allow for the extra result item in your result processing. See the [JPQL BNF](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/jpql.html#bnf)